# can we use azure load balancer on a multiple Azure openai services in azure

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-openai

I have resource group in azure. I have created 3 Azure openai service but I am wondering if it is possible to place a load balancer on these 3 app services to balance the load between them, Is it possible to do so?? Or Which load balancer technique I need to apply to balance multiple request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Load Balancer or Azure Application Gateway to distribute incoming traffic across multiple instances of your application. All your three open AI services can be added in backend pool.

- Created load balancer and configured virtual network,
  [image]
  [image]
- Added two open AI services in Azure load balancer backend pool,
  [image]
- You can create a health probe to monitor the health and latency of your backend instances.
- Define a rule on load balancer to define how traffic should be distributed across the backend instances.
  [image]

Azure Load Balancer supports two types of distribution algorithms:

**1.Round-robin distribution**: Distributes traffic evenly across all healthy instances.

**2. Source IP affinity distribution**: Distributes traffic based on the source IP address of the client.

Reference links for load balancing MS [document 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-load-balancing-azure), MS [document 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/cross-region-overview).

Comment: hi sir,the openai service did not provide the ip address,but the endpoint and key.how to set the backend pool with ip address?

Comment: How would this help with multiple instances of Azure OpenAI?  They each have their own key.  You can't just redirect the traffic, the code has to know the key for the right endpoint correct?